# Obtener id de usuario

Tags: php, android, cuenta-usuario

Quisiera que me ayudarán estoy realizando una aplicación móvil y tengo dos tablas en mi base de datos una llamada "usuarios" y la otra "actividades" dentro de esta segunda tabla tengo una llave foránea del id del usuario, lo que quiero es obtener el id del usuario logueado y que este se inserte en la tabla actividades, cada vez que un usuario publique una actividad

Les dejo el código php que utilizo para hacer una inserción en la tabla actividades

```
    <?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$imagen= $_POST['foto'];
$nombre = $_POST["Titulo"];
$des = $_POST["Descripcion"];
$aut = $_POST["Autor"];
$fec = $_POST["Fecha"];
$hor = $_POST["Hora"];

 require_once('../registro/Conexion_db.php');

 $sql ="SELECT idActividad FROM actividades ORDER BY idActividad DES";

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $id = 0;

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 $id = $row['idActividad'];
 }

 if($imagen!="no imagen"){
 $path = "uploads/$id.png";
 $actualpath = "https://pitav2.000webhostapp.com/$path";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO actividades (foto,titulo,descripcion,autor,fecha_entrega,hora_entrega) VALUES ('$actualpath','$nombre','$des','$aut','$fec','$hor')";
 }else{
    $actualpath = "sin imagen";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO actividades (foto,titulo,descripcion,autor,fecha_entrega,hora_entrega) VALUES ('$actualpath','$nombre','$des','$aut','$fec','$hor')";
}
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen));
 echo "Subio imagen Correctamente";
 }

 mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
 echo "Error";
 }
```

Comment: Cuando se loguea guardalo en una variable de sesion y luego usa esa variable.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varias alternativas para poder guardar la id del usuario conectado. Una vez el usuario haga el login, puedes guardar el dato de la id en una de estas variables de php, `$GLOBALS, $_COOKIE o $_SESSION`.

Lo más recomendable sería utilizar la de `$_SESSION` y lo tendrías que hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $id
```

Donde la variable `$id` la obtienes de una select cuando el usuario haga el login.

Answer (score 0):

la primera cuestion, te funciona la query?? es que tienes BY idActividad DES y sería DESC, en cuanto a tu pregunta, cuando te logueas me imagino que antes consultas tu tabla usuarios, por lo que puedes obtener el id de usuario y guardarlo como te comenta Iñigo en una variable de session algo como `$_SESSION['logged'] = $id`, es así de simple, y como consejo y evites duplicar código yo esta parte

```
if($imagen!="no imagen"){
   $path = "uploads/$id.png";
   $actualpath = "https://pitav2.000webhostapp.com/$path";
   $sql = "INSERT INTO actividades (foto,titulo,descripcion,autor,fecha_entrega,hora_entrega) VALUES ('$actualpath','$nombre','$des','$aut','$fec','$hor')";
 }else{
$actualpath = "sin imagen";
$sql = "INSERT INTO actividades    (foto,titulo,descripcion,autor,fecha_entrega,hora_entrega) VALUES        ('$actualpath','$nombre','$des','$aut','$fec','$hor')";
 }
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
     file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen));
     echo "Subio imagen Correctamente";
  }
```

la pondría así

```
$actualpath = $imagen!='' ? 'https://pitav2.000webhostapp.com/'.$path : '';
$sql = "INSERT INTO actividades (foto,titulo,descripcion,autor,fecha_entrega,hora_entrega) VALUES ('$actualpath','$nombre','$des','$aut','$fec','$hor')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
     file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen));
      echo "Subio imagen Correctamente";
}
```

realmente no se que envias en el campo foto, veo que es un post y no $_FILE, pero en cualquier caso si no tiene foto cambialo por string vacio a menos que quieras guardar el literal en la base de datos.
Saludos